# Read multiple csv elements from each row into seperate lists

Tags: python, list, csv, filereader

I have a CSV and I want to read each row's 6th element into one list and each row's 7th element into another. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import math

#open csv file and create fie reader
with open('weightheightdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    #skip first 2 lines (header lines)
    next(reader)
    next(reader)

    #create list of e values using the 9th column of each row
    actualWeight = []
    predictedWeight = []
    for row in reader:
        actualWeight.append(float(row[6]))
        predictedWeight.append(float(row[7]))
```

I am getting the error: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`
on the line: `predictedWeight.append(float(row[7]))`.

Comment: You're getting the `TabError` because you're mixing tabs and space characters for indentation. Use one or the other — with spaces being the preferred way to do it. Most IDEs and text editors can be configured to automatically convert one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The line prior to it has 2x four spaces, this line has 1x four spaces and 1x tab. Make both lines consistent with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine. I tested it myself. Just check your indentation on the line. Make sure you used the same tab or 4 spaces you used throughout the file. That's actually all there is to the error. Python is very strict about indentation.